# How to save current login user? user_id may not be NULL

Tags: django

I have this error:

> appname_mymodel.user_id may not be NULL

```
def form_view(request):
    user = request.user
    f_form = FForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if f_form.is_valid():
            f_form.user = user
            f_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'f_form': f_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py:

```
class FForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude =['user']
```

How to save current login user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form doesn't have a `user` attribute so it is useless to assign to it. What you should do instead is:

```
if f_form.is_valid():
    my_model = f_form.save(commit=False)
    my_model.user = user
    my_model.save()
```

This way the form will construct a `MyModel` instance, but will not attempt to save it to the database. Then you can fill the `user` field and save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide the necessary data as an instance argument:

```
f_form = FForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, \
        instance = MyModel(user=user))
if request.method == "POST":
    if f_form.is_valid():
        f_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```